# Is it possible to enable logging of RDP connections / disconnections under Windows XP and Windows 7?

Tags: rdp, connection, windows-event-log, eventviewer

As the title suggests, I'm trying to [keep an eye on RDP connections / disconnections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2514450/how-can-i-programmatically-determine-in-python-when-someone-connects-into-my-wi) to a couple of machines. One's running Windows XP and one's running Windows 7.

I've checked the event logs on the Windows XP machine and there's nothing mentioned in there. Is it just a Windows 2003 Server feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know if there's something specific for RDP, btw you could

1. enable an [Audit Policy for Logons](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/aptopnode.mspx?mfr=true) on the workstation (you can do it via GPO if you're on a Active Directory domain or you can do it on a single workstation editing its Local Security Policy)
2. check Events in Security with Event Code = 528 (User logged in) and Logon Type = 10 (Remote Interactive, so RDP like connections)

you can query Events i.e. using [LogParser](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=890cd06b-abf8-4c25-91b2-f8d975cf8c07) ([GUI here](http://visuallogparser.codeplex.com/Wikipage)) and maybe load them in a DB for future analysis

Comment: Thanks. I'm using Python to parse the loging messages as part of a larger suite of applications (no need to use logparser).